# Кастомизация Snackbar

Tags: android, adapter

Задача в следующем. Есть xml файл с разметкой. Можно ли запихнуть его в Snakbar так как это допустим делается с помощю адаптера для ListView? Если да то подскажите пожалуйста как. Заранее Благодарю)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть несколько способов. [Самый простой](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33441214/3212712) - получить доступ к разметке `SnackBar`-а и изменить её:

```
// Create the Snackbar
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(containerLayout, "", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
// Get the Snackbar's layout view
Snackbar.SnackbarLayout layout = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) snackbar.getView();
// Hide the text
TextView textView = (TextView) layout.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

// Inflate our custom view
View snackView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_snackbar, null);
// Configure the view
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) snackView.findViewById(R.id.image);
imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
TextView textViewTop = (TextView) snackView.findViewById(R.id.text);
textViewTop.setText(text);
textViewTop.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

// Add the view to the Snackbar's layout
layout.addView(snackView, 0);
// Show the Snackbar
snackbar.show();
```

Этот способ опасен тем, что вмешиваясь в стандартное поведение можно получить баги и падения на разных ОС и девайсах.

---

Также есть сложный способ переопределения почти всего в `SnackBar` - [вот он](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41154330/3212712). По идее он самый надёжный, ибо страхует от внезапных изменений на уровне ОС.

---

Вот ещё вариант переопределения разметки через `xml` и ресурсы: [тык](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34285656/3212712). Но в комментах пишут, что может и не сработать, т.к. в системе что-то поменялось.

Answer (score 0):

`Snackbar` не должен содержать ничего кроме текста и кнопки